# How to access roster file data from an SLS file

Tags: salt-stack

I am using `salt-ssh` to configure salt-minions.

I need the IP address of the minion in the mid of the state file execution to put it in some configuration files.

My problem is that I can't use the grains to get this information as there will be multiple network interfaces and multiple IPs and the only fact I know is that the IP of the minion will be the IP in the roster file from which the `salt-master` did the ssh in to the minion.

How can I get this information?
How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible at the moment, unfortunately. That might be a nice feature, though.